A problem with \times in math mode
in my thesis everything was working fine then suddenly something went wrong with \times in math mode now not work and numbers appear like this 110^5 instead of 1x10^5
I think this happened after I added nomenclature and abbreviation with \usepackage{acronym}
with this simple example,
`\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
$10 \times 10$

$10 \cdot10$
\end{document}`


this the preamble
 \immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}


\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz, lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{calligra,frcursive,xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pagestyle{plain}
\linespread{1.3} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth }{0.3pt}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue}
%% itemize
\usepackage{enumitem}
%% table
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false % <-- important
]{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{physics}
\graphicspath{{./image/}}
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{1.5cm}


the problem comes with babel's arabic option.

Please always make your example as small as possible (good way to actually learn what the problem was) and in a form where one can just copy the example and use it as is. Here is it broken into fracments. And most of the packages in the sniplet are most likely not relevant to the problem (hence the minimality).
